# Cannot get func from PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-proptypes

I cannot figure out why this import or any other does not work:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
    import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    //import { PropTypes } from '@material-ui/core';

    interface IProps {
        value: string;
        onChange?: PropTypes.func;
    }

    const textField = (props: IProps) => {
        return (
            <div>HI</div>
        );
    };

    export default textField;
```

The error I receive is:

ts-app/node_modules/@types/prop-types/index"' has no exported member 'func'

I am looking in this file and it seems to clearly have such a member:

```
export const func: Requireable<(...args: any[]) => any>;
```

perhaps one day I will understand React and how these dependencies work, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PropTypes.func` is a value (intended to be used in a `propTypes` property of a stateless function component or static property of a component class), but you are trying to use it as a type.  Instead, you could manually write the underlying type:

```
onChange?: (...args: any[]) => any;
```

or hopefully a more specific one appropriate for your application.

I [filed an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27630) for the poor error message.